# How to perform an (SQL LIKE) search in jqgrid loadonce mode

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I know how to use the search feature on JQGrid where you send the request back to the server each time a filter or search is performed.  Doing so if you code the php correctly you can perform a `LIKE` search on the data in the column.  For example, if a column contains the string `Hello World` and you search on `world` you will get a match.  Yet if you use the `loadonce` option with jqGrid not only will `world` fail to return a match but `hello` will as well.

Is there a way to do this natively with the `loadonce` option in JQGrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you use [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) with default parameters of the `filterToolbar` method so the `defaultSearch: 'bw'` ('begin with') will be used. You should use `defaultSearch: 'cn'` ('contain') option to have `*text*` matching. For example

```
$("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
    {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
```

Moreover you can additionally use `ignoreCase: true` option of jqGrid to have case insensitive matching.